# Call the same id in the same function load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call an id from a function load, yes the same id, I am also using the setInterval to repeat the process every ten seconds.
At issue is I'm doing in localhost and I do not know how to call himself.

here is the code:

```
    <div ng-include="'modules/carruselps/views/carruselp.client.view.html'" id="c1"></div>  



<script type="text/javascript">

function carga() {
    $('#c1').load('#c1');
}
    setInterval("carga();",10000); 
</script>
```

my localhost direction is: http://localhost:3000/#!/

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but it's considered much better to pass a function reference to *setInterval* than a string to be evaluated, e.g. `setInterval(carga,10000)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify URL to load from

```
$('#c1').load(window.location.href + ' #c1 > *');
```

Comment: I have done but when they pass the ten seconds the div disappears

Comment: @ElíasHernández Check response, make sure there is no `<div id="ci"><div id="c1">`, make sure in response there is `#c1` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your setInterval function throws error : Uncaught ReferenceError: carga is not defined

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals.

You can use any of the following method to call the setInterval.

```
function carga() {
    console.log('calling')
}
setInterval(carga,100);
```

// Or

```
function carga() {
    console.log('calling')
}
setInterval(function(){
    carga();
},100);
```

Comment: While the function reference version of `setInterval()` is recommended, the OP's version does work.  This is not the issue the OP is having.  My guess is that you tried this in jsFiddle and got that error, but it was actually caused because you didn't have `fuction carga() {...}` in the global scope like the OP does.